# Count of orders by each customer in each month of a year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in MySQL, one of them having customers

```
______________
customers     | 
______________|
id | name     |
______________|
1  | John     |
2  | Wick     |
______________
```

Then 2 order tables, each of them are

```
______________________________________
call_order
______________________________________
id | customer_id | created_at
______________________________________
1  | 1           | 2019-02-19 15:07:48
2  | 2           | 2019-03-19 15:07:48
3  | 1           | 2019-02-19 15:07:48
```

and second order table is

```
______________________________________
direct_order
______________________________________
id | customer_id | created_at
______________________________________
1  | 2           | 2019-02-19 15:07:48
2  | 1           | 2019-03-19 15:07:48
3  | 1           | 2019-02-19 15:07:48
```

What I want to achieve is

```
____________________________________________
customer | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr ... | Total
____________________________________________
John     |  0  |  3  |  1  |  0      |  4
Wick     |  0  |  1  |  1  |  0      |  2
```

I want to query in a way that I get record of each customer in every month of an year which must be ordered by the total. It means the customer with the highest total must be at the top.

Comment: what is your actual query?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all` and conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select c.name,
       sum( month(created_at) = 1 ) as Jan,
       sum( month(created_at) = 2 ) as Feb,
       . . .
       sum( month(created_at) = 12 ) as Dec,
       count(*) as total
from customers c join
     ((select customer_id, created_at
       from call_orders
      ) union all
      (select customer_id, created_at
       from direct_orders
      ) 
     ) o
     on o.customer_id = c.id
group by c.name
order by total desc;
```

I imagine you also want restrictions on the year, so orders are from the same month rather than the same month in multiple years.